# Transforms not applying to the dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and would like to understand something.

I am loading MNIST as follows:

```
transform_train = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Resize(size, interpolation=2),
     # transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
     transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
     transforms.Normalize((mean), (std))])


trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True,
                                      download=True, transform=transform_train)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

However, when I explore the dataset, i.e. `trainloader.dataset.train_data[0]`, I am getting a tensor in range [0,255] with shape (28,28).

What am I missing? Is this because the transforms are not applied directly to the dataloader but only in runtime? How can I explore my data otherwise?

Comment: what is the `size` you defined?

Comment: what is `mean` and `std` you are using?

Comment: They are mean=0.1307, std=0.3081, size=32.

Comment: I figured out the problem though, it appears that the `.ToTensor()` method should be applied after Resize and HorizontalFlip, I don't know why though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The transforms are applied when the `__getitem__` method of the `Dataset` is called. For example look at the `__getitem__` method of the `MNIST` dataset class: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L62

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    """
    Args:
        index (int): Index
    Returns:
        tuple: (image, target) where target is index of the target class.
    """
    img, target = self.data[index], self.targets[index]

    # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    # to return a PIL Image
    img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode='L')

    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return img, target
```

The `__getitem__` method gets called when you index your `MNIST` instance for the training set, e.g.:

```
trainset[0]
```

For more information on `__getitem__`: [https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

The reason why `Resize` and `RandomHorizontalFlip` should be before `ToTensor` is that they act on [PIL Images](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) and all the datasets in Pytorch for consistency load the data as `PIL Image`s first. In fact you can see that here they force that behavior through:

```
img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode='L')
```

Once you have the `PIL Image` of the corresponding index, the transforms are applied with

```
if self.transform is not None:
    img = self.transform(img)
```

`ToTensor` transforms the `PIL Image` to a `torch.Tensor` and `Normalize` subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation you provide.

Eventually some transforms are applied to the label with

```
if self.target_transform is not None:
    target = self.target_transform(target)
```

Finally the processed image and the processed label are returned. All of this happens in a single `trainset[key]` call.

```
import torch
from torchvision.transforms import *
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

transform_train = Compose([Resize(28, interpolation=2),
                           RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
                           ToTensor(),
                           Normalize([0.], [1.])])

trainset = MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True,
                 transform=transform_train)
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
print(trainset[0][0].size(), trainset[0][0].min(), trainset[0][0].max())
```

shows

```
(torch.Size([1, 28, 28]), tensor(0.), tensor(1.))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. It is still not clear to me what the ToTensor method actually does and why it wouldn't be commutative though

Comment: maybe it's better if you ask that in a separate question